# How To Create a Floating Menu Card Box in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to replicate an UI from a figma screen. But I'm stuck with this widget, and I wonder if material (or any external) package has anytying similiar to this, that could help me, or I'll need to create this by hand? Its like a floating menu card that its called by the center blue button to give the user the ability to navigate between all screens.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this package https://github.com/chinabrant/popup_menu

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:popup_menu/popup_menu.dart';
import 'package:popup_menu_example/gesture_demo.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Popup Menu Example'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  PopupMenu menu;
  GlobalKey btnKey = GlobalKey();
  GlobalKey btnKey2 = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    menu = PopupMenu(items: [
      // MenuItem(title: 'Copy', image: Image.asset('assets/copy.png')),
      // MenuItem(title: 'Home', image: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.white,)),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'Mail',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.mail,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'Power',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.power,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'Setting',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.settings,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
      MenuItem(
          title: 'PopupMenu',
          image: Icon(
            Icons.menu,
            color: Colors.white,
          ))
    ], onClickMenu: onClickMenu, onDismiss: onDismiss, maxColumn: 1);
  }

  void stateChanged(bool isShow) {
    print('menu is ${isShow ? 'showing' : 'closed'}');
  }

  void onClickMenu(MenuItemProvider item) {
    print('Click menu -> ${item.menuTitle}');
  }

  void onDismiss() {
    print('Menu is dismiss');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    PopupMenu.context = context;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          // action button
          IconButton(
           key: btnKey,
            icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
            onPressed: () {
              maxColumn();
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            key: btnKey2,
            icon: Icon(Icons.memory),
            onPressed: () {
              maxColumn();
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: GestureDetector(
                onLongPress: () {
                  //maxColumn();
                },
                child: MaterialButton(
                  height: 45.0,
                  //key: btnKey,
                  child: Text('Show Menu'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void onGesturesDemo() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GestureDemo()),
    );
  }

  void checkState(BuildContext context) {
    final snackBar = new SnackBar(content: new Text('这是一个SnackBar!'));

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  void maxColumn() {
    PopupMenu menu = PopupMenu(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        // lineColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        maxColumn: 3,
        items: [
          MenuItem(title: 'Copy', image: Image.asset('assets/copy.png')),
          // MenuItem(
          //     title: 'Home',
          //     // textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.tealAccent),
          //     image: Icon(
          //       Icons.home,
          //       color: Colors.white,
          //     )),
          // MenuItem(
          //     title: 'Mail',
          //     image: Icon(
          //       Icons.mail,
          //       color: Colors.white,
          //     )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Power',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.power,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Setting',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'PopupMenu',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
        ],
        onClickMenu: onClickMenu,
        stateChanged: stateChanged,
        onDismiss: onDismiss);
    menu.show(widgetKey: btnKey);
  }

  //
  void customBackground() {
    PopupMenu menu = PopupMenu(
        // backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        // lineColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        // maxColumn: 2,
        items: [
          MenuItem(title: 'Copy', image: Image.asset('assets/copy.png')),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Home',
              // textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0, color: Colors.tealAccent),
              image: Icon(
                Icons.home,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Mail',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.mail,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Power',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.power,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'Setting',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.settings,
                color: Colors.white,
              )),
          MenuItem(
              title: 'PopupMenu',
              image: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                color: Colors.white,
              ))
        ],
        onClickMenu: onClickMenu,
        stateChanged: stateChanged,
        onDismiss: onDismiss);
    menu.show(widgetKey: btnKey2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so from the UI, you're supposed to have a bottomNavbar with three screens, the middle screen contains a container/card with different buttons in it.

i have created something similar for this purpose, i hope it helps.

Bottom Nav Bar:

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomNavBar> createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    const FirstScreen(),
    const SecondScreen(),
    const ThirdScreen()
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex,
        children: screens,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: const Color.fromRGBO(50, 201, 209, 1),
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) => setState(() => currentIndex = index),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        iconSize: 30,
        items: const [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.home_outlined,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.shopping_cart_outlined,
            ),
            label: 'Orders',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.production_quantity_limits_rounded,
            ),
            label: 'Products',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Card/container widget:

```
class ArrowClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 30);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 + 10, size.height - 30);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2 - 10, size.height - 30);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 30);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(ArrowClipper oldClipper) => false;
}
```

The screens:

```
class ThirdScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ThirdScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          ClipPath(
            clipper: ArrowClipper(),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              child: Container(
                height: 300,
                width: double.infinity,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                      spreadRadius: 2,
                      blurRadius: 5,
                      offset: const Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: const [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: const [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: const [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                )),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```